# Search keys get variable is in subsequent search pages and so search not returning any more results

Tags: 8, search

I have a small form that posts the search page. The resultant link is like this:

http://www.example.com/search/node?keys=test

Then subsequent searches don't work, because the form includes the keys variable in the form definition:

```
<form action="/search/node?keys=test" ...
```

This means that subsequent searches don't work. How do I fix this?

**Another detail** - If I type the search page directly into the address bar, i.e. `www.example.com/search/node`, I get `"Your search returned no results"` - suggesting it is doing a search just when accessing the page directly. I think this may be related to the issue, but I can't work out why it is occurring.

Comment: Another detail - if I type the search page directly into the address bar, i.e. www.example.com/search/node, I get "Your search returned no results" - suggesting it is doing a search just when accessing the page directly. I think this may be related to the issue, but I can't work out why it is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to POST to **/search/node** as all its parameters are retrieve from query parameters. As such, you can make your basic form use the GET method with your `keys` input field. For example:

```
<form action="/search/node" method="get">
  <input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." name="keys" value="" size="15" maxlength="128">
  <input type="submit"value="Search">
</form>
```

As for the "Your search returned no results" on loading **/search/node**, that's the default behavior.